# Keep my session active android app

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an Android app and I can't figure out why my session doesn't stay active!

I create an login layout and when I successfully get a connection, my userLocalStore as true! So when I get back to the home of this application and again press the login button, I want it to just show my account details.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
case R.id.accLogin:
    if (userLocalStore.getUserLoggedIn() == false){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Compte.class));
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
    }
```

But it doesn't work! Is there a thing like "Cookie" for an Android app?

Here is my userLocalStore code :

```
public class UserLocalStore {

public static final String SP_NAME ="userDetails";
SharedPreferences userLocalDatabase;

public UserLocalStore(Context context)
{
    userLocalDatabase = context.getSharedPreferences(SP_NAME, 0);
}

public void storeUserData(User user)
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = userLocalDatabase.edit();
    spEditor.putString("name", user.name);
    spEditor.putString("surname", user.surname);
    spEditor.putString("username", user.username);
    spEditor.putString("password", user.password);
    spEditor.putInt("age", user.age);
    spEditor.commit();
}

public User getLoggedInUser() {
    String name = userLocalDatabase.getString("name", "");
    int age = userLocalDatabase.getInt("age", -1);
    String username = userLocalDatabase.getString("username", "");
    String password = userLocalDatabase.getString("password", "");
    String surname = userLocalDatabase.getString("surname", "");

    User storedUser = new User(name, age, username, password, surname);
    return storedUser;
}

public void setUserLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn)
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = userLocalDatabase.edit();
    spEditor.putBoolean("LoggedIn", loggedIn);
    spEditor.commit();
}

public boolean getUserLoggedIn()
{
    if (userLocalDatabase.getBoolean("LoggedIn", false))
    {
        return false;
    }else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public void clearUserData()
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = userLocalDatabase.edit();
    spEditor.clear();
    spEditor.commit();
}
```

}

I just found my error ! just have to change

`public boolean getUserLoggedIn()
    {
        if (userLocalDatabase.getBoolean("LoggedIn", false))
        {
            return false;
        }else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }`

to

```
public boolean getUserLoggedIn()
{
    if (userLocalDatabase.getBoolean("LoggedIn", false))
    {
        return true;
    }else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Tanks for help !

Comment: You should provide the code for `userLocalStore` where you save and read the data.

Comment: You should update your question with the code. Also, you seem to be inverting `userLocalStore.getUserLoggedIn()` which is probably the error

Comment: Ok thanks, i just updated my post ! I'm going to see what you said !

Comment: Thank ! i just found it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `SharedPreferences` to emulate cookies. You can make a file that's accessible to your entire app (all activities) opened via a filename.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("a filename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
// writing
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("cookie", "value");
editor.commit();
// reading
String cookie = sharedPref.getString("cookie", "defaultValue");
```

Comment: Must i put this on my userLocalStore ? i put the register thing in writing and login in reading ?

Comment: I just realised, i already have a sharedpreference but doesn't know it was acting like a cookie

Comment: It does. Does this answer your question? If so you can mark this answer as accepted (and upvote if you want!)